# OpenSwing Open Window Tab Bar - 6 tab maximum

Tags: java, swing

We are using the OpenSwing Framework for our application and ran into a problem with the `viewOpenedWindowIcons()` method.

We have noticed that when we open more than 6 windows (depending on screen size), the "opened windows tab bar" does not display tabs for these additional windows.
Does anyone know if there is a scroll function that we can implement to have the ability create more than six tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I never use swing and this framework more than 1 year. just some suggestion may help you...

1. change the look&feel to system default , may not have this problem.
2. please find org.openswing.swing.mdi.client.WinIconsPanel, which is a JPanel with FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT).and you could make it scrollable with the scrollbar hidden,and add two arrow(left,right) button on the side of it.